# loader appearing all time i come to homescreen in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am learning firebase with getx for state managagement

Home screen showing all data of available categories.

I have used repository class and controller class to divide code

My query is simple that whenever i come to home screen its showing Loader for categoryfetching...may b its bcz i am using Get.put() method and all time its calling controller's init method..

I tried to make getter for finding instance with Get.find() method..but its showing error on first time to home screen..not initailized..

**I want loader should de shown only once when i come to home screen first time only..**

how to do it?

```
class CategoryController extends GetxController {
  RxList<CategoryModel> allCategories = <CategoryModel>[].obs;
  RxList<CategoryModel> popularCategories = <CategoryModel>[].obs;
  RxBool isLoading = false.obs;
  final repo = Get.put(CategoryRepository());

  @override
  void onInit() {
    // TODO: implement onInit
    super.onInit();
    assignCategories();
    print('I am called init of category controller');
  }

  void assignCategories() async {
    isLoading.value = true;
    allCategories.value = await repo.fetchCategories();
    popularCategories.value =
        allCategories.where((cat) => cat.parentId == '').toList();
    isLoading.value = false;
  }
}
```

category repository for fetching records from firebase collections

```
class CategoryRepository extends GetxController {
  final _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future<List<CategoryModel>> fetchCategories() async {
    List<CategoryModel> categories = [];
    final list = await _db.collection("Category").get();
    categories = list.docs.map((e) => CategoryModel.fromSnapshot(e)).toList();
    return categories;
  }
  
}
```

and this is my screen where i am showing all categories

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.put(CategoryController());

  
    return SafeArea();
```